# Example of a non-commutative rings with identity that do not contain non-trival ideals and are not division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for an example of a non-commutative ring, $R$, with identity s.t $R$ does not contain a non-trival 2 sided ideal and $R$ is not a division ring

Comment: Of coruse, if you mean left (right) ideals, then you are talking about a division ring. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If "ideal" means "two-sided ideal," then the [Weyl algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) $\mathbb{C} \langle x, y \rangle / (xy - yx - 1)$ is an example.  So is $\mathcal{M}_n(R)$ for any division ring $R$ and $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean two-sided ideals, you are looking for simple rings (that are not division rings):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring

E.g. as in the wikipedia article, is the ring of matrices (of a certain size) over a field. Clearly this is not a division ring since not every matrix is invertible (matrices with zero determinants are not invertible).